# Tubeplayer get videoUrl before playing

Tags: jquery

I have multiple instances of the tubeplayer (http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin) in a moodboard.

```
players = $.tubeplayer.getPlayers();
```

gives me the player instances, from each instance I can retrieve the videoUrl like so:

```
for(var p in players) {
    players[p].getVideoUrl();
}
```

The problem is that this videoUrl is only set after the play button is hit on the youtube video, so if someone doesn't hit the play button I'm left with an undefined videoUrl.
I've set autostart: true, that works offcourse, but isn't ideal, because you have to pause al the players manually.

Anyone has an idea how to fetch the videoId / videoUrl without playing the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in the videoID property:

```
$(playerId).tubeplayer('data').videoID
```